# Problems with Promise.all

Tags: javascript, promise

I have to get back to this forum for help because I can't still make a 'Promise.all' work!

First, I have this function, which is supposed to return a promise:

```
const myFetch = (a, b) => {
    var url;
    // some stuff bulding 'url' using a and b
    fetch(url).then(response => {
        return response.json();
    }
})
```

The idea is that the above function returns a promise, whose value, once resolved, is the json object. I have checked that the json is actually valid. If I replace the "return ..." line with the line below I actually get a valid json:

```
response.json().then(res=> console.log(res))
```

Second, I have this for loop, after which I expect to have an array of promises:

```
promises = [];
for (...){
    // some other stuff
    promises.push(myFetch(a, b))
}
```

Eventually I execute this code:

```
Promise.all(promises)
.then(responses => { // <=== Here I get all "undefined"
    responses.forEach(response => {
        console.log(response);// <=== Here I get all "undefined"
    });
    // some other stuff that I can do only after all fetches are complete
})
```

I expect the .then portion to be executed only once all promises are resolved, and also expect "responses" to be a list of all the json responses from the individual promises above. Still, I get a string of "undefined". The impression is that the portion of code within .then is running even though the promises are not yet resolved.

What did I do wrong? How can I be sure to have all the json objects from the individual fetches before proceeding? (note, I cannot use await/async). Thanks

Comment: your `myFetch()` isn't returning anything, you need to do something like `return fetch(url).then(...);`

Comment: There is a return, inside the .then

Comment: Are you sure all your requests are giving proper response as if one fails you promise.all fails

Comment: Yes, I also used a .catch (not shown above) to verify it

Comment: @Bob-it the return doesn't return to your `myFetch()` call through, it returns to the callback provided in the `.then()`

Comment: You are probably right. Now I'm trying with two "return", as suggest in Terry Lennox's answer, it seems to be working

Comment: Perfectly logical ...now :-). Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return the promise from the fetch call, otherwise the promise chain will be broken, once you do this, all should play nice!

Something like so should work:

```
const myFetch = (a, b) => {
    var url;
    // some stuff bulding 'url' using a and b
    return fetch(url).then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
};
```

A snippet example:

```js
const myFetch = (url, a, b) => {
  return fetch(url).then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
};

function testMyFetch() {
    promises = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        promises.push(myFetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/" + (i+1)));
    }
    Promise.all(promises).then(result => console.log("Promise.all result:", result));
}
testMyFetch();
```

Comment: Thanks @terry-lennox, it works. I had tried with a return in either the fetch or the response line, but not in both!

Comment: Yeah, I've done this before a bunch of times and scratched my head for a long while :-D, we learn from our mistakes I guess.